# c++ Crash when shared_ptr goes out of scope...after running at least 100,000 times successfully

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb, shared-ptr

This code has run 100,000's of times before crashing around (6hrs of running in tests). When the crash happens it occurs when shared_ptr goes out of scope...the purpose of this function is to fill the passed in vector of shared_ptr ( in this case), with the messages filtered by type...So not all messages in historyQueue get added. this newly filled vector is used later to send these PMs...this function is also called by other threads which is why there is a LockGuard which is typedef for standard lockguard (typedef std::lock_guard LockGuard)

```
bool MessageHistory::getMessages(vector< shared_ptr<ProtocolMessage> >& v,bool allMessages, bool playerFilter, int playerId, MessageFilter* filter)
{
    LockGuard lock(historyMutex);
    v.resize(historyQueue.size());
    unsigned count=0;

    for_vector(historyQueue,i)
    {   PM pm=historyQueue[i];//PM is a shared_ptr as well items in histortQueue
        const int uid=pm->GetPlayerDest();
        bool pmok =false;
        int pmtype=0;



        if(!pm->GetPid() || !pm->GetMid())
            continue;

        pmtype=(pm->GetPid() << 16) + pm->GetMid();



        if(filter && pmtype)
            pmok=filter->messageIsOk(pmtype);

        if ((allMessages || uid == -1 || (playerFilter && uid == playerId))
        && (filter == 0 || pmok))
        {   if(count>=v.size())
            {   break;
            }
            v[count++]=pm;
        }

    }//crash happens here after 100,000's of successful calling of this function
    v.resize(count);
    return true;
}
```

backtrace:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f74546b51b0 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f74546b51b0 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000005a7f41 in _M_release (this=0x7f7454204230)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:146
#2  ~__shared_count (this=0x7f747dff0d38, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:551
#3  ~__shared_ptr (this=0x7f747dff0d30, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:751
#4  ~shared_ptr (this=0x7f747dff0d30, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:93
#5  MessageHistory::getMessages (this=0x7e3cf18, v=..., allMessages=false, 
    playerFilter=true, playerId=-2141, filter=0x7e3cf88)
    at MessageHistory.cpp:177
```

relevant part function calling getmessages :

```
if (handIsActive.IsLocked() && history.size() > 0)
    {   vector< shared_ptr<ProtocolMessage> > lp;
        history.getMessages(lp,playerId,&noChatFilter);
        shared_ptr<ProtocolMessage> pm(new HandSoFar(lp));
        GameQueue::sendMessage(address, pm);
}   }
```

the vector lp is not used again after this...

any help would be greatly appreciated....thanks

Comment: In nearly all cases I've seen that fall into the "this dynamic management worked for X amount of time or number of cycles, then suddenly failed, the *reason* is because undefined behavior at some point corrupted artifacts that eventually reared at this time. Ex: if the vector containing the shared pointers that happened to be passed in to this call had been victim of a buffer breach+ovewrite, the shared pointers would be toast and a release would likely fault. Honestly, where I you I would turn Valgrind loose on this.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for your response...the vector passed in is empty its populated by this function...I have attempted valgrind but for this to occur it require a large load on system for testing and for some reason when running valgrind with that load because of timeouts sockets start dropping

Comment: @AlessioMack That clearly spells "race condition" to me. If timing matters, race conditions become likely

Comment: @sehe i thought the same thing...but my lockguard should protect against that ...

Comment: Not for the vector passed in. It might be concurrently used elsewhere. Also, I cannot see the other sites accessing `historyQueue` :)

Comment: @AlessioMack I guess I didn't make that quite clear. Running Valgrind wasn't suggested as something to do to try to reproduce this error while under said-watchful eye. Rather it is to do *regardless* and carefully scrutinize its output, which should be clean, as any number of issues it reports *can* eventually lead to such a problem as yours. I.e. just because your error didn't emerge under VG doesn't mean something it reports could not potentially lead to said error under the right circumstances.

Comment: @sehe i added edited posts to include part that calls this...it  pretty straight forward and is not used after that..

Comment: @WhozCraig oh i see what u mean...there are lots of false positives in the report with mem-leak flag...to focus on this issue would i be looking at possible mem leaks as well in that report...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My only hunch is that you have [UB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) elsewhere.

It could be a race on the vector that you pass in as a reference (`v`). It's easy to forget about synchronizing access to that.

---

Slightly off-topic: May I suggest a little simplification.

Reducing code/separating concerns always helps in keeping complexity, and therefore bug-rate, down:

```
bool getMessages(vector<PM> &v, Query const& query)
{
    LockGuard lock(historyMutex);

    v.clear();
    std::copy_if(historyQueue.begin(), historyQueue.end(), back_inserter(v), query);

    return true;
}
```

There were quite a number of confusing/conflicting things there:

- the condition

  ```
      if (count >= v.size()) {
          break;
      }
  ```

  could never be true due to the `resize()` up front
- `v.resize(count)` afterwards too... this just begs `copy_if` (actually, even better would be `v.assign_if` but the library didn't think of that. Boost Range would do it).
- there's so much mixing and redundancy here:

  ```
  if (!pm->GetPid() || !pm->GetMid()) // 1.
      continue;
  ```

  right here, we already know that `pmtype` cannot be zero:

  ```
  pmtype = (pm->GetPid() << 16) + pm->GetMid();

  if (filter && pmtype) // pmtype cannot be zero 
      pmok = filter->messageIsOk(pmtype);
  ```

  `pmok` is partially defined now, only if `filter!=0`... And then it gets hairy in the use:

  ```
  if ((allMessages || uid == -1 || (playerFilter && uid == playerId)) && (filter == 0 || pmok)) {
  ```

  Obviously easier would be to do

  ```
  bool pmok = !filter || filter->messageIsOk(pmtype);

  if ((allMessages || uid == -1 || (playerFilter && uid == playerId)) && pmok) {
  ```
- I think it's iffy that `allMessages` doesn't do what it says. It actually does something opposite to what `playerFilter==false` achieves now. I think it's likely that you misplaced the parentheses there, ***or*** you should call the flag `allUserIds`? (I've assumed the latter).
- You could simplify the interface using `optional<int> playerId`. However, since apparently `uid==-1` is a magic value anyways, why don't you make the `-1` signal 'no userid filter' as well?
- what is `for_vector` (Surely... it's not a macro to write a loop? Again, that's what `copy_if` is for).

Using these tweaks, the Query class can be completely implemented like this:

```
struct Query {
    bool allPlayers;
    int playerId;
    MessageFilter *filter;

    Query(bool allPlayers = true, int playerId = -1, MessageFilter* filter = nullptr) :
        allPlayers(allPlayers), playerId(playerId), filter(filter)
    {
    }

    bool operator()(PM const& pm) const {
        if (!(pm->GetPid() && pm->GetMid()))
            return false;

        int  pmtype = (pm->GetPid() << 16) + pm->GetMid();
        bool pmok   = !filter || filter->messageIsOk(pmtype);

        int  uid         = pm->GetPlayerDest();
        bool matchPlayer = uid == -1 || allPlayers || (playerId != -1 && uid == playerId);

        return pmok && matchPlayer;
    }
};
```

And the use would be like e.g.

```
std::vector<MessageHistory::PM> v;
hist.getMessages(v, MessageHistory::Query { false, 42 }); // only uid 42; no MessageFilter
```

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e824cb48b8b2e332)</kbd>**

```
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

using LockGuard = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>;
std::mutex historyMutex;

struct ProtocolMessage { //stub
    int GetPlayerDest() const { return 1; }
    int GetPid()        const { return 1; }
    int GetMid()        const { return 1; }
};

struct MessageFilter {
    virtual bool messageIsOk(int)  const { return true; }
    virtual ~MessageFilter() { }
};

struct MessageHistory 
{
    using PM = std::shared_ptr<ProtocolMessage>;

    struct Query {
        bool allPlayers;
        int playerId;
        MessageFilter *filter;

        Query(bool allPlayers = true, int playerId = -1, MessageFilter* filter = nullptr) :
            allPlayers(allPlayers), playerId(playerId), filter(filter)
        {
        }

        bool operator()(PM const& pm) const {
            if (!(pm->GetPid() && pm->GetMid()))
                return false;

            int  pmtype = (pm->GetPid() << 16) + pm->GetMid();
            bool pmok   = !filter || filter->messageIsOk(pmtype);

            int  uid         = pm->GetPlayerDest();
            bool matchPlayer = uid == -1 || allPlayers || (playerId != -1 && uid == playerId);

            return pmok && matchPlayer;
        }
    };

    bool getMessages(std::vector<PM> &v, Query const& query)
    {
        LockGuard lock(historyMutex);

        v.clear();
        std::copy_if(historyQueue.begin(), historyQueue.end(), back_inserter(v), query);

        return true;
    }

  private:
    std::deque<PM> historyQueue;
};

int main() {
    MessageHistory hist;

    std::vector<MessageHistory::PM> v;
    hist.getMessages(v, MessageHistory::Query { false, 42 }); // only uid 42; no MessageFilter
}
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed response and examples...This looks like a more effiecient way to do what im doing....i apologize for the  mixing and redundancy, most of that was for sanity check, trying to figure out what was causing crash...ie. initially crash happened on this line: filter->messageIsOk(pm_>getType()); which i brought logic from gettype into this function with this: int  pmtype = (pm->GetPid() << 16) + pm->GetMid(); which it no longer crashed on that line but at end of scope...as if one of the Pm's in historyqueue was corrupt...I will implement your suggestions...

Comment: btw i would upvote this answer because of good info and examples but it will not allow me because of my rep...sorry